# mysqldump segmentation fault on large --where=(id IN ...)

Tags: mysql, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when using mysqldump with large --where=(id IN ...).

```
mysqldump --verbose --host=myhost --user=myuser -ppass mydb mytable --insert-ignore --no-create-info --where="id IN (6162591,5796486,5796495,6162586, ...)"
```

Result

```
-- Connecting to mydb...
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.60, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: myhost    Database: mydb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.5.60-0+deb8u1-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES latin1 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
-- Retrieving table structure for table flash_images...
-- Sending SELECT query...

--
-- Dumping data for table `mytable`
--
<!-- - WHERE:  id IN (6162591,5796486,5796495,...,4 -->
Segmentation fault
```

I have 732 IDs in my list. Fails with 400 too. Works with 200.

I tried `--skip-quick` to force memory buffer and `--skip-extended-insert`, it fails too.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be the error ?

Thank you.

Comment: A segmentation fault is caused by a bug in mysqldump.  Perhaps you could run your dump in batches of 200?   But if the dump would succeed, there's no guarantee you could use the insert statement itself without running into memory problems.

Comment: Related: [Mysql Bug #93008: mysqldump crashes with segmentation fault on last 5.6 and 5.7 versions](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed a mysqldump bug in version 10.13.

I made a script to break id list in batches of 200, and that solution works.

Comment: Had the same problem and also resorted to splitting up the IDs into batches.